# What does Lenstra's MILP do?

Tags: reference-request, integer-programming

Honestly I do not understand why Lenstra's MILP is in $P$ if the number of integer dimensions is fixed.

Here is what Lenstra says in 'http://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/presentations/Lenstra81.pdf' in section 5. Mixed integer linear programming.

> "At a certain point in the algorithm we
>   have to decide whether a given vector $y\in\mathbb R^n$ belongs to $τΚ$. This can be done by
>   solving a linear programming problem with $k — n$ variables".

Here $n$ is number of integer variables and $k-n$ is number of real variables that are not restricted to be integers.

By 'At a certain point in the algorithm' I take it as that first the algorithm finds an integer point in the first $n$ coordinates and by 'we
have to decide whether a given vector $y\in\mathbb R^n$ belongs to $τΚ$' I take it that at this set coordinate of first $n$ coordinates it tests if the remaining $k-n$ real variables pass Khachiyan's test.

> Is this right or close to being right? If this is not what Lenstra does then what exactly does he do and what exactly does he mean by 'At a certain point in the algorithm'?